# How does this code snippet run the final function after both ajax requests have completed?

Tags: javascript

This example code was given in the You Don't Know JS book, which is supposed to explain concurrent async processes in Javascript. I don't understand it:

```
var a, b;

function foo(x) {
  a = x * 2;
  if (a && b) {
    baz();
  }
}

function bar(y) {
   b = y * 2;
   if (a && b) {
     baz();
   }
}

function baz() {
   console.log( a + b );
}

// ajax(..) is some arbitrary Ajax function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url.1", foo );
ajax( "http://some.url.2", bar );
```

Kyle says that the **if condition** around **baz()** is a **gate** that should open once **a** and **b** has a value, i can not understand that part, am i missing something, if **a or b** has no value **baz** would not be called and the function should not wait for both **a and b** to have a value, is there any explanation for that code?

Comment: I have added a revised version of Kyle's code, which is IMHO less confusing. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if a or b has no value baz would not be called and the function should not wait for both a and b to have a value

Indeed - if `foo` runs before `bar`, `(a && b)` will evaluate to `(x * 2 && undefined)`, so `baz` will not run *on that* invocation of `foo`.

But after that point, the global variable `a` *is* defined, so once `bar` runs *after* that, `bar` will assign to `b`, and the `if` condition will be fulfilled, and `baz` will be called.

The `foo` and `bar` don't *wait* for the values to be defined - rather, *if* all necessary values are defined at the time they run, `baz` is invoked. So, if both ajax calls are successful, the final ajax call will result in `baz` being called regardless. (as long as `x * 2` and `y * 2` are not falsey)

Either:

- `foo` runs, condition fails. Then `bar` runs, condition succeeds, `baz` is called. OR
- `bar` runs, condition fails. Then `foo` runs, condition succeeds, `baz` is called

This is still a pretty inelegant way to do things. The logic would be much clearer if you used `Promise.all`, without reassigning global variables and checking conditions:

```
const doFetch = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
Promise.all([
  doFetch('http://some.url.1'),
  doFetch('http://some.url.2')
])
  .then(([x, y]) => {
    // do stuff with x and y, if needed
    baz();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this specific code in Kyle Simpson's book is unnecessarily confusing.

Maybe this revised version will help you understand the concepts better along with the approved answer:

```
var keyA, keyB; // Initially, both have the value: undefined

function checkOne() {
  keyA = true;
  if ( keyA && keyB ) {
    openGate();
  }
}

function checkTwo() {
   keyB = true;
   if ( keyA && keyB ) {
     openGate();
   }
}

function openGate() {
   console.log( "Gate Opened!" );   // Will happen only if keyA and keyB === true
}

// ajax(..) is some arbitrary Ajax function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url/1", checkOne );
ajax( "http://some.url/2", checkTwo );
```